# Kerberos Resourced based constrained delegation in cross realm setup

Tags: java, active-directory, kerberos, kerberos-delegation

I'm trying to use latest JDK 8 to perform [resource based constrained delegation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-sfu/3bff5864-8135-400e-bdd9-33b552051d94), and seems to be running into issues getting the service ticket for the last leg of the S4U2Proxy call.

Here is my setup:
Two microsoft AD forest with two way forest authentication enabled.

- ForestA: forestA.com
- ForestB: forestB.com
- Front end service is in ForestA with SPN of http/myappserver.forestA.com
- Back end service in ForestB with SPN of http/backend.forestB.com
- The user being impersonated is in ForestB with username of userB.

I've successfully utilized S4U2Self protocol and retrieved the service ticket for userB to Front end service in ForestA. However, when trying to utilized S4U2Proxy to get service ticket to back end service in ForestB, the request fails with error code kerberos error 12.

Upon investigating the audit logs from event Viewer on the domain controller of ForestB, it indicates the error message is 0xC000019B (Event Id 4769), which seems to be related to some generic trust setup issue.

Any further requests with the same payload with result in Kerberos error code 28 back from ForestB's domainController. Likely due to caching of kerberos ticket from before?

Update:

This setup works fine if the front end service and the user are in the same forest, and the back end service is in a different forest.

It also works when front end service and back end service are in one forest, and the user is in a different forest.

Comment: The last paragraph of your problem statement is a bit confusing, can you edit/expand on it a bit inside of your question?  -->  "*I have tried with cases where end user is in ForestA, or when the backend service is in ForestA, either case works fine with S4U2Proxy call. The only time it does not work is when the end user and the end service are in one domain, and the front end service is in a different domain.*"

Comment: Also, is userB, the front-end service, and the back-end service, all in the root domain of each forest?

Comment: I've edited the description to clarify. Also yes, this is all assuming there is one root domain in each forest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing the matter with Microsoft, it was confirmed that this specific case is not supported by Microsoft AD by design. Specifically if front end service is in one forest, and the user and resource service are in a different forest, then this use case is not supported.

Hopefully this helps for someone that encounter this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Errorcode 12 is KDC_ERR_POLICY

I experienced the same, where the midtier was Linux, running Apache2 as reverse proxy, on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

MIT implemented resource-based constrained delegation protocol in 2021, with Kerberos V.5 1.19.
9 years after Microsoft extended the Kerberos protocol in 2012.

The solution was to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, which come with Kerberos 1.19. Then it worked.

I found out by creating a Forest, 2x DC, SQL, mid-tier, IIS server and user laptop in Azure cloud.
By inspection with Network Monitor in DC, I could see how Tickets was interchange differently, comparing IIS and Apache2. Then I travelled through MIT release notes and saw their announcement for Resource-Based Constrained Delegation in 1.19.